# was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, struct, undeclared-identifier

I'm getting back to c++ because they want that from me for the school but I ran into problem.

I defined struct like this:

```
struct Member{
    string Name;
    string Surname;
    Member* Next;
};
```

and 2nd structure:

```
struct List{
    string Name;
    Member* First;
    int Size;
};
```

than below I had a function:

```
int AddToList(Member* Member, List* List){
    if(List->First == nullptr){
        List->First = Member;
        List->First->Next = nullptr;
        return 1;
    }
    Member* Current = List->First->Next;
    while(Current != nullptr){
        Current = Current->Next;
    }
    Current = Member;
    Current->Next = nullptr;
    return 2;
}
```

But I get an error than the line:

```
Member* Current = List->First->Next;
```

> error: 'Current' was not declared in this scope.

I tried to change the function like this:

```
int AddToList(Member* Member, List* List){
    Member* Current = new Current;
    if(List->First == nullptr){
        List->First = Member;
        List->First->Next = nullptr;
        return 1;
    }
    Current = List->First->Next;
    while(Current != nullptr){
        Current = Current->Next;
    }
    Current = Member;
    Current->Next = nullptr;
    return 2;
}
```

But I get the same error just on the line:

```
Member* Current = new Current;
```

Although I though this won't helped but I just wanted to try. I though the function wasn't aware of what Member* means but than it would also have problems with the arrows and stuff as it wouldn't know whats it made of. It seems weird to me than only that 1 line seems to not know what Member* is.

Comment: Proper indentation is always good but even better when the question pertains to variable scoping.

Comment: Well they never required me to do that so I learned to navigate without it, didn't realized that.

Comment: Having variables with the same names as types is not only really confusing but also the reason for your problems.

Comment: @JiříMatyáš Is, something being a requirement,  the only reason to learn it? Isn't ease of reading the code, not reason enough to learn proper indentation?

Comment: Well to be honest, my room mate just showed me how it should look like and I can't really navigate in that. I feel better working with it as it is now. But I believe its going to backfire very soon :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have variables with the same names as their types:

```
int AddToList(Member* Member, List* List) {
    // Member and List are the parameters, *not* the types
    ...
    Member* Current = List->First->Next; // syntax error, Member is a variable
}
```

You need to change the name of these variables to something else. A common convention in C++ is to use either lowerCamelCase or snake_case for variable names:

```
int AddToList(Member* member, List* list) {
    // Member and List are the types
    // member and list are the parameters
    ...
    Member* current = list->first->next; // Works now
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Didn't know than this can backfire like this.